# Image composition based on "pattern matrix"

Tags: python-3.x, image, numpy

I want to stitch together `c` rgb images in numpy resulting into a larger image. Images are represented as numpy arrays. I however, do have the following constraints:

1. I do want to stitch together `c` rgb images in shape `n * m = c`, stored in a dictionary, here an example of a dictionary containing 21 images:

```
c_images = { 5:numpy.array[[x,y,3]], 1:numpy.array[[x,y,3]], ... 21:numpy.array[[x,y,3]]}
```

2. I have a "pattern" matrix of size `n * m = c`, in which each the indexes of the images `0...c` are scattered randomly. A randomly generated "pattern matrix" of size `n = 3`, `m = 7`, `c = 21`looks like the following

```
P_matrix = [[14, 3, 19, 5, 16, 18, 0],
            [17, 1, 13, 7, 6, 15, 11],
            [4, 9, 10, 12, 8, 20, 2 ]]
```

What would be the best way to use the pattern matrix, to compose a larger numpy array, based on `c` images ?

Comment: Could you provide some code and show what you have got so far? Do all of the images have the same size?  Se also [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi thanks for the outline, I edited my post, but need just read about the MRE, I keep updating it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [`np.block`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.block.html) can help you. Not all the images have to be the same size but they need to *fit together*. First some example data:

```py
import numpy as np
n, m = 3, 4
img_size = np.array([3, 3])

img_list = [np.zeros(img_size)+i for i in range(n*m)]
# [array([[1., 1., 1.],  array([[2., 2., 2.],   ...array([[12., 12., 12.],
        # [1., 1., 1.],         [2., 2., 2.],             [12., 12., 12.],
        # [1., 1., 1.]]),       [2., 2., 2.]]),,          [12., 12., 12.]])

rnd_idx = np.random.permutation(range(n*m)).reshape((n, m))
# array([[ 9, 10,  0,  4],
#        [ 3, 11,  6,  5],
#        [ 2,  8,  7,  1]])
```

Than you need to create a nested list of your images based on the given pattern, `np.block` does the rest for you:

```py
img_list_nested = [[img_list[col] for col in rows] for rows in rnd_idx]

img = np.block(img_list_nested)
# array([[ 9.,  9.,  9., 10., 10., 10.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
#        [ 9.,  9.,  9., 10., 10., 10.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
#        [ 9.,  9.,  9., 10., 10., 10.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
#        [ 3.,  3.,  3., 11., 11., 11.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  5.,  5.,  5.],
#        [ 3.,  3.,  3., 11., 11., 11.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  5.,  5.,  5.],
#        [ 3.,  3.,  3., 11., 11., 11.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  5.,  5.,  5.],
#        [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  8.,  8.,  8.,  7.,  7.,  7.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
#        [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  8.,  8.,  8.,  7.,  7.,  7.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
#        [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  8.,  8.,  8.,  7.,  7.,  7.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```